# LINQ OrderBy the first array AND update a second array holding indexes

Tags: arrays, linq, sorting

Given an array of 3-dimensional vector objects, and a second array with indexes,

how do I sort the first array using LINQ, such that the index array gets updated as well?

For instance:

```
public Vector3[] vectors = new Vector3[]{new Vector3(4,2,2), new Vector3(2,2,2), new Vector3(3,2,2) };

public int[] indexes = new int[]{0,1,2};

vectors = vectors.OrderBy(vector => vector.x); //order the vector3 objects by x-coordinate
```

end result:

```
(2,2,2),  (3,2,2),  (4,2,2)
```

This, however, leaves behind indexes, which should have been updated to:

```
1, 2, 0
```

How to address this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no link between your vectors and your indexes, so they can't be sorted together.

Instead of making to different arrays, try something like this:

```
IList<KeyValuePair<int, Vector3>> v = new List<KeyValuePair<int, Vector3>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, Vector3>(0, new Vector3(4,2,2)),
    new KeyValuePair<int, Vector3>(1, new Vector3(2,2,2)),
    new KeyValuePair<int, Vector3>(2, new Vector3(3,2,2))
};
```

Then all you have to do is sort:

```
v = v.OrderBy(x => x.Value.x);
```

You can still access your sorted indexes array through `v.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray()` and your vectors array through `v.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray()`.